# DVI and Display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dvi

I Have a PC that has VGA, HDMI, DisplayPort, and DVI Outputs. I have 2 Monitors on which one is square and the other is Rectangle.

I need to use both of these Monitors side by side (Dual Monitors). The square Monitor is not having HDMI Receiver, but has DVI and VGA.

I have connected the rectangle monitor to the PC using the HDMI To HDMI Cable. I tried using a converter (DisplayPort to VGI) from the DisplayPort to VGI on Square Monitor for Dual Monitor, and it is not working.

Can I use the DVI to DVI Cable from PC to Square Monitor and use Dual Monitor?

Comment: Hey there, I edited your question for clarity but I can't seem to understand VGI (it could be either VGA or DVI). But DisplayPort is a digital connection and both VGA/DVI are analog connections. Why can't you directly plug in the square monitor with a DVI cable?

Comment: @CaldeiraG DVI has 3 flavors: analog, digital and combined. Digital DVI signal is actually compatible with HDMI and its analog signal is compatible with VGA.

Comment: the PC has DVI and VGA direct out, so I too am wondering why the OP is fussing with an adapter

Answer (score 1):

DVI is confusing because there are multiple variants that can carry partially compatible or incompatible signals, despite connectors physically matching. These are:

- DVI-D (digital only)
- DVI-A (analog only)
- DVI-I (combined DVI-A and DVI-D)

DVI-D devices work only over DVI-D and DVI-I connections. DVI-A devices work only over DVI-A and DVI-I connections.

Your graphics card doesn't have a digital-to-analog converter, so it only has a DVI-D output. This means that it will only work with DVI-D and DVI-I displays.

I assume *"VGI"* is a typo for DVI, because to my knowledge DP→VGA converters are not available (and don't make much sense anyway). DP to DVI converter produces DVI-D signal. Your monitor didn't accept it, so it must have a DVI-A input. It means that it won't accept DVI-D signal from your graphics card.

DVI to VGA adapters won't work, because they work only on DVI-I and DVI-A outputs, which your graphics card doesn't have.

Comment: Maybe you could add at first that he should simply plug a single DVI cable from his video card to the square monitor, which will work for sure.

Comment: @NatsuKage I don't think it will work. The monitor probably has DVI-A input.

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good image showing the visual differences between DVI port layouts ( https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/DVI_Connector_Types.svg/181px-DVI_Connector_Types.svg.png )